# Is there a way to mass rearrange parts of a file name for many files in Windows Command Prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line, rename, batch-rename

I have a folder of files where the names of the files are dates. I need to change the names of the files from `mm-dd-yyyy.eXtension` to `yyyy-mm-dd.eXtension`.

This is what I currently have:

```bath
03-31-2019.txt
03-31-2020.txt
03-31-2021.txt
03-31-2022.txt
```

This is what is desired:

```bath
2019-03-31.txt
2020-03-31.txt
2021-03-31.txt
2022-03-31.txt
```

I understand the `ren` function but not sure how to mass rename them all distinct names that originate from the initial name. I have looked around and found more help with the simple `ren` function, but nothing to just reorder the name.

Below are some things I found that help with `ren` and give some additional thoughts, but still not what I need.

[How to rename files in Windows cmd command prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396610/how-to-rename-files-in-windows-cmd-command-prompt)
[Batch program to rename file which has spaces in file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19133556/batch-program-to-rename-file-which-has-spaces-in-file-name?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: A  rename command that can take regular expressions would be useful to you. 

Linux has one  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961255/rename-files-using-a-regex-with-bash  But i'm not sure if you can get it in Windows command line.

I use a program called Regex Renamer.  I find the windows command prompt's FOR command to be pretty ugly for many things, and it might be easier to use a programming language like python than to use the windows for command!

Comment: It would be much easier in **PowerShell** than using `cmd.exe` and Batch. Any reason not to?

Comment: It is on a work computer that is restricted to only certain programs and such. Windows Command Prompt and a very restricted Python is all I have

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler to use a GUI third-party software for that.

A Swiss-knife product you may use is the free
[Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/)
that can basically do all operations of any type whatsoever.

Here it is on your data using regex:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String Manipulation of a variable and define the layout of the name according to the desired regrouping of the substrings:

```bath
1.echo.Date   : %date%  
2.echo.Weekday: %date:~0,3%  
3.echo.Month  : %date:~4,2%  
4.echo.Day    : %date:~7,2%  
5.echo.Year   : %date:~10,4%
```

[image]

---

```bath
@echo off 

for %%i in (??-*.txt)do set "_n=%%~ni" && =;(
    %ComSpec% /v /c "ren "%%~i" !_n:~6,4!-!_n:~0,2!!_n:~2,3!%%~xi" );=
```

---

- To traverse different files and not just/exclusively in the `.txt` eXtension, and in case of running in the same folder, ignoring applying to the `.bat` itself, then don't use `"-"` in the bat name, and try this loop:

```bath
@echo off 

for /f delims^= %%i in ('dir /a:a /b *-*.*')do set "_n=%%~ni" && =;(
    %ComSpec% /v /c "ren "%%~i" !_n:~6,4!-!_n:~0,2!!_n:~2,3!%%~xi" );=
```

For an isolated test proposal, you can create a folder and run this bat in that folder, where it will be possible to create files for testing in the same name layout and monitor/visualize the use of manipulations using substrings:

```bath
@echo off 

:: Deleting/creating files for testing ::
cd /d "%~dp0" && 2>nul del /q /a .\*.txt
for %%i in (19,20,21,22)do cd.>03-31-20%%~i.txt

for /f delims^= %%i in ('dir /a:a /b *-*.*')do set "_n=%%~ni" & echo\ &&  =;(
    %ComSpec% /v /c "echo\// Original file name.eXtension = !_n!%%~xi"
    %ComSpec% /v /c "ren "%%~i" !_n:~6,4!-!_n:~0,2!!_n:~2,3!%%~xi" 
    %ComSpec% /v /c "echo\variable index from 6 get 4 places == !_n:~6,4!"
    %ComSpec% /v /c "echo\variable index from 0 get 2 places == !_n:~0,2!"
    %ComSpec% /v /c "echo\variable index from 2 get 3 places == !_n:~2,3!"
    %ComSpec% /v /c "echo\and put back original file eXtension == %%~xi"
    %ComSpec% /v /c "echo\// File renamed to: !_n:~6,4!-!_n:~0,2!!_n:~2,3!%%~xi" );=
```

- Outputs:

```bath
// Original file name.eXtension = 03-31-2019.txt
variable index from 6 get 4 places == 2019
variable index from 0 get 2 places == 03
variable index from 2 get 3 places == -31
and put back original file eXtension == .txt
// File renamed to: 2019-03-31.txt

// Original file name.eXtension = 03-31-2020.txt
variable index from 6 get 4 places == 2020
variable index from 0 get 2 places == 03
variable index from 2 get 3 places == -31
and put back original file eXtension == .txt
// File renamed to: 2020-03-31.txt

// Original file name.eXtension = 03-31-2021.txt
variable index from 6 get 4 places == 2021
variable index from 0 get 2 places == 03
variable index from 2 get 3 places == -31
and put back original file eXtension == .txt
// File renamed to: 2021-03-31.txt

// Original file name.eXtension = 03-31-2022.txt
variable index from 6 get 4 places == 2022
variable index from 0 get 2 places == 03
variable index from 2 get 3 places == -31
and put back original file eXtension == .txt
// File renamed to: 2022-03-31.txt
```

---

## Some further reading:

- **[`For /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**
- **[`For /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)**
- **[`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**
- **[`Set variable=variable:substrings` | DOS - String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**
- **[DelayedExpansion (Refer: `%ComSpec% /v /c !Expand_RunTime_Variable!`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)**